# The Do-It-Yourself Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, sudoku, tiling

## Can you solve this puzzle?

[image: Puzzle]

You may (or may not) have noticed that this puzzle doesn't seem to have any pieces. How can it be solved without pieces? The short answer it can't. That's why for this puzzle you must create the rectangular pieces intended for this puzzle. To find these pieces you must use the grids below and solve for them. Once you have all the pieces put them together on the puzzle base in the shape of the silhouette provided. First valid solution gets the checkmark. Good Luck!

[image: Grids]

Comment: Nice puzzle, what is its source?

Comment: Entirely made by me

Comment: Whoa!! Brilliant :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing from ABcDexter's solution,

> the green highlighted numbers from the solved Sudoku are copied to the blank grid, and become the clues for a new Shikaku puzzle. [Link 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shikaku) [Link 2](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/shikaku.html)
>  [image]

Solving the next step:

> The final solution to the Shikaku is this:
>  [image]
>  If there's a request in the comments, I'll write a full step-by-step solution to this. The general solve path is to start with the larger numbers, since they are more constrained in how they can fit in.

Assembling the "G":

> Taking the individual boxes, we have our pieces for assembling the "G". If we are allowed to rotate the pieces, then this puzzle would be too easy, so assume that these pieces have to remain in the same orientation.
>  I don't have a fully-logical step-by-step solution for this; I initially noted that the long 9 piece and the 2-tall,4-wide piece each had to go either on the top or the bottom, and had to be on opposite sides.
>  The final assembly I found is:
>  [image]

Comment: Wow!! Who'd thought that there was a Shikaku in that! Awesome :)

Comment: You got it bang on! You were correct with your assumption that the pieces have to remain in the solved orientation and got the exact solution I had!

Answer (score 3):

Well, Sudoku was pretty logical :)

> [image: solved sudko]

---

Recreating the (weird)G ...

> [image: probably rightly spotted]

Comment: You have the sudoku solved correctly... unfortunately your next step is incorrect